# What happens if the UK wants to remove you from itself but your passport has, for example, expired or been lost?

Tags: passports, passport-renewals, removal, deportation

What is the procedure like then? Do they obtain one on your behalf from your national embassy? Politely request you to do so as promptly as required? How does such a situation play out?

I'm interested in the UK, but also in whether or not the answer is universal across every country or if the question is actually made different by specifying a country.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do not have a suitable travel document but need to leave the UK (either by choice, or for a 'voluntary departure' or because the Home Office is removing you), they will not rely on someone else to provide a document. They will issue you an [IS137 One Way Travel Document](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/488177/Home_Office_travel_documents_guidance_v6.0EXT_clean.pdf). This is essentially a piece of paper with a passport photo stapled to it and some biographic details.

The Home Office state that it is the holder's responsibility to ensure they are able to enter their destination country. I believe in cases of removal, the Home Office will have an agreement in place that you will be accepted.